# ASP.NET CORE MVC AJAX

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to put a partialview when the value of a dropdownlist changes.
With my code it works but when I want to send data to the controller using post method I always have null values (the controller parameter always have null data). I have seen a lot of different ways to do it but no one works for me.

My view ajax code:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#ProjecteId").on("change", function () {
        var request = JSON.stringify({
            'ProjecteId': $('#ProjecteId').val()
        });
        console.log(request);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            url: '/Consultas/MostrarTipusPersona',
            dataType: 'html',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: request,
            success: function (data) {

                console.log('sample', data);
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

My controller:

```
         [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult MostrarTipusPersona(ProjecteModel pm)
    {
        return PartialView("_Ciutada", new Ciutada());
    }
```

Comment: __Something I can spot:__

 In the type field of your ajax object:

_type : "post"_

Also please clarify where you are getting nulls? Is it in the return of the Ajax or the data you are posting?  Some more info and I can help you.

Comment: Hi @Terrance00, I receive the null data in the controller, the parameter ProjecteId is always null. I've modified my post to clarify this, lot of thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**First validate the client side data:**

Since no html was provided please log your json:

```
var request = ...
console.log(request);
$.ajax(...)
```

**Make sure your server side expects the right data**

As of your code, the server side expects an object with a string member. So let's give it that. We will create an object representing your json object you are sending to the server:

```
public class ProjectedModel
{
    public string ProjecteId {get;set;}
}
```

Now modify your method to expect this model:

```
public IActionResult MostrarTipusPersona(ProjectedModel model)
```

*PS: It looks like your client side ajax method is expecting json. I would recommend removing `dataType: "json"` from your ajax method as the datatype will be partialhtml view. (Just receive it as a string - or expand your question so we can be sure.)*

**EDIT:**

Passing a string value seems to be the issue then, there are two things to try:

**(1)Convert the data to string with `toString()` method**

```
 var request = JSON.stringify(
        {'ProjecteId': ($('#ProjecteId').val()).toString()
    });
```

**(2) Do it inline like this:**

```
var request = JSON.stringify({
    'ProjecteId': "'" + $('#ProjecteId').val() + "'"
});
```

Off course your other option would be to simply send it an integer.

Comment: First of all, lot of thanks for helping me :)
The request have these data: {"ProjecteId":"2"}, I think it's correct. 
The model ProjecteModel (without [FromBody]) is not null but the property ProjecteId have a null value :(
The correct dataType is html, and it works (datatype: "html"), I 've changed it just for try other ways.
If I use [FromBody] the ProjecteModel is null..

Answer (score 0):

I've the solution, just put contetType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I thought you wanted to send json specifically. Anyway, the edit should work now.

Comment: Well, the time will come when you want to send json - the above answer can be your guide. Happy coding.